# How to take String as input using Scanner, when input is of the form(below)?

Tags: java, string

Input:

```
abc

def

feg

cba
```

This is what I am doing, of course wrong!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P {

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = x.nextInt();

        for (int j=0; j<t; j++) {
            String p[j] = x.nextLine();
        }

        for (j=0; j<p.length(); j++) {
            for (k=0; k<p.length(); k++) {
                if (p[j] = reverse(p[k])) {
                    int q = p[k].length();
                    System.out.println(""+q+((q/2)+1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem ? are you trying to input string in place of int ?

Comment: I'm assuming there is supposed to be a number of lines input first?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? This doesnt give us any clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: ohh yes there is int before the string, its 4...sorry

Comment: and what is your problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what is wrong with your current code? Does it give you compiler errors or runtime errors?

Comment: P.java:12: error: ']' expected
     String p[j]=x.nextLine();
              ^
P.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
     String p[j]=x.nextLine();
               ^

Comment: I have to take those strings and check if any two are palindrome pair and if so then have to print the middle char of that string.

Comment: `if (p[j] = reverse(p[k]))` #1: `=` is assignment, not a test for equality.  #2: Don't use `==` on strings anyway, use `equals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you wrote is because of this code:

```
for (int j=0; j<t; j++) {
    String p[j] = x.nextLine();
}
```

If you want to create a String array this is how you do it:

```
String[] p = new String[t];
```

It also needs to be declared outside of your for-loop. I suggest something like this:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = x.nextInt();
    String[] p = new String[t];

    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
        p[j] = x.nextLine();
    }

    for (j=0; j<p.length(); j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**The new code you posted:**

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = x.nextInt();
String p[] = new String[n];

for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
    p[j] = x.nextLine();
}

for (j = 0; j < p.length(); j++) {
    for(k = 1; k < p.length(); k++) {
        if (p[j] = reverse(p[k])) {
            int q = p[k].length();
            System.out.println(""+q+((q/2)+1));
        }
```

**With all the corrections I've commented your code should look like this:**

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = x.nextInt();
String[] p = new String[t];

for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
    p[j] = x.nextLine();
}

for (int j = 0; j < p.length(); j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k < p.length(); k++) {
        if (p[j] = reverse(p[k])) {
            int q = p[k].length();
            System.out.println("" + q + ((q / 2) + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting something else:  
Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
     int t=x.nextInt();
     String p[]=new String[n];
     for(int j=0;j<t;j++){
      p[j]=x.nextLine();
     }
     for(j=0;j<p.length();j++)
     {for(k=1;k<p.length();k++){
         if(p[j]=reverse(p[k])){int q=p[k].length();
        System.out.println(""+q+((q/2)+1));
        }

Comment: 11: error: n cannot be resolved


15: error: j cannot be resolved


15: error: j cannot be resolved


15: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]


15: error: j cannot be resolved


16: error: k cannot be resolved


16: error: k cannot be resolved


16: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]


16: error: k cannot be resolved


17: error: j cannot be resolved


17: error: The method reverse(String) is undefined for the type P


17: error: k cannot be resolved


17: error: k cannot be resolved

Comment: The `n` in `String[] p = new String[n];` needs to be an `int`. So something like `int n = 10;`, or you can use a number directly. So `String[] p = new String[10];`

Comment: It's also important that you write `String[] p = ...;` and not `String p[] = ...;` (so these [] goes immediately after String)

Comment: And in the second for-loop you need to make sure you write `int j = 0; `and not just `j = 0;`

Comment: Same thing goes for you third for-loop

Comment: 16: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]


17: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]


18: error: The method reverse(String) is undefined for the type P

Comment: Update your question with `Edit:` and then post your current code.

Answer (score 0):

at a glance, it seems like your scoping is off. The variable p in

```
for (int j=0; j<t; j++) {
        String p[j] = x.nextLine();
    }
```

is declared and then immediately discarded. You probably want something more like

```
    String[] p = new String[t];
    for (int j=0; j<t; j++) {
        p[j] = x.nextLine();
    }
```

similarly with q in the loop below

```
    int q = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<p.length; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<p.length; k++) {
            if (p[j] = reverse(p[k])) {
                q = p[k].length();
                System.out.println(""+q+((q/2)+1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped.

more information about variable scope in Java:

[variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Comment: Please check what to do now ? I am getting this:
11: error: n cannot be resolved 15: error: j cannot be resolved 15: error: j cannot be resolved 15: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[] 15: error: j cannot be resolved 16: error: k cannot be resolved 16: error: k cannot be resolved 16: error: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[] 16: error: k cannot be resolved 17: error: j cannot be resolved 17: error: The method reverse(String) is undefined for the type P 17: error: k cannot be resolved 17: error: k cannot be resolved